# immutable js Map() - don't understand take() and skip()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm new to web development and learning React/Redux and following a tutorial from http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html.

I'm trying to understand and confuse about the take() and skip() methods we used in the following code. I can sort of understand the usage, but where did we get them?? JS method? immutable.js method? I have searched google for hours. But no luck. Can someone please help?? Thanks for your time:

```
import { List, Map } from 'immutable';
export function next(state) {
  const entries = state.get('entries');
  return state.merge({
    vote: Map({ pair: entries.take(2)}),
    entries: entries.skip(2)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/take

http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/skip

`take()`
Returns a new Collection of the same type which includes the first amount entries from this Collection.

Example: `take(amount: number): this`

`skip()`
Returns a new Collection of the same type which excludes the first amount entries from this Collection.

Example: `skip(amount: number): this`

This is from the immutable js map function

Comment: Thank you so very much :-) I guess I didn't look hard enough in the immutable.js library. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. Everybody makes mistakes :)